# How to add shadow on buttons with new UIButton Configuration way?

Tags: swift, uikit, uibutton

I am trying to refactor buttons in the app. Previously, shadows on buttons could be implemented easily using `layer.shadowColor` and similar properties. However, with the new Configuration style, I am unsure how to create shadows on buttons.

I attempted to search for solutions on Google, but unfortunately, I couldn't find any.

```
public class MainButton: UIButton {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

private func setup() {
    var config = UIButton.Configuration.borderedTinted()
    config.baseBackgroundColor = .red
    config.buttonSize = .medium
    config.cornerStyle = .capsule

    let handler: UIButton.ConfigurationUpdateHandler = { [self] button in
        switch button.state {
        case .highlighted:
            button.configuration?.baseBackgroundColor = .blue
        default:
            button.configuration?.baseBackgroundColor = .red
        }
    }

    config.titleTextAttributesTransformer =
    UIConfigurationTextAttributesTransformer { [self] incoming in
        var outgoing = incoming
        outgoing.font = UIFont().withSize(16)
        outgoing.foregroundColor = isEnabled ? .white : .gray
        return outgoing
    }

    config.contentInsets = .init(top: 4, leading: 4, bottom: 4, trailing: 4)
    configuration = config
    configurationUpdateHandler = handler
}

override var isEnabled: Bool {
    didSet {
        var updatedConfiguration = self.configuration
        updatedConfiguration?.background.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.configuration = updatedConfiguration
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The `shadowXXX` properties in `CALayer` still works. What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: yes sweeper is right, shadowColor works in all configuration state.. please describe your problem with screenshot

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Then if I had such a MainButton class it would be necessary or enough to add a function like addShadow on to it. I thought there would be a solution with configuration.

`func addShadow() {
         self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
         self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
         self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
     }`